# Mis-typed crontab line caused strange operation

Tags: cron, centos6

So, I meant to put in the following entry in my crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /command/to/run/every/5/minutes
```

but accidentally typed

```
**/5 * * * * /command/to/run/5/times/a/minute
```

So, the command ran 5 times in immediate succession. Is this an unexpected behavior, or some poorly documented way to run things multiple times.

I am running Centos 6 and cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64

Comment: Could you let us know what your distribution and cron version are?

Comment: I am using Centos5 and running cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64

Comment: The RPM is for CentOS 6 but you said you are on CentOS 5. Can you double check what you wrote and maybe edit your question with the correct detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, I do not observe this behavior on CentOS 6. What I do see is that the job runs every minute, which is what you would expect.

The fields are a sequence of ranges or values. The double asterisk is obviously a typo, but according to the man page, the asterisk is a replacement for the "first-last" range. So you have two ranges there. "0-59" (every minute) and "0-59/5" (once every five minutes). The union of these is "every minute" which is what I am seeing.

If your job ran 5 times in rapid succession (i.e. more than once a minute) you should look elsewhere for the reason. It is not the crontab line.

Comment: Strange thing is, when I corrected the typo, it was only running once per 5 minutes.

Comment: Once per five minutes is the expected behavior of `*/5`.

Comment: I understand that its the expected behavior. What I meant was that if the file was running multiple times because of some non-cron behavior, that it stopped when the typo was fixed in the cron.